# Transitions between panoramas in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I have set of equirectangular panorama pictures, I'm displaying them using Three.js sphere geometry similar to this example: http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_panorama_equirectangular.html

I added buttons to the scene to allow navigation between panoramas. I would like to have transition while traveling between panoramas. It should be similar to Google Street View transitions as much as possible.

Can someone share some ideas/directions how to implement this using three.js?

Comment: I just asked an exactly the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45637939/three-js-panorama-cube-to-zoom-in-and-transition-into-a-different-panorama-cube Any update since 2014?