# Three.js: Panorama Cube to Zoom In and Transition Into a Different Panorama Cube

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new to Three.js. I am using this example with 6 image cube for panorama effect, where one can pan, zoom in and out around cubes.

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=panorama#webgl_panorama_equirectangular

I want to figure out how, at maximum zoom-in level, I can transition user into a different panorama cube (with different image source), mapped to this particular cube part.  So I would, sort of, open the next scene to take user further to the next level in his journey.

This is nearly what Google Street View does when you click on arrows to move forward down the road.

I do not see many examples out there. I researched and saw this may be possible with creating 2 scenes? Any ideas how to make it functional I would appreciate.

Comment: I found an unanswered duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27566155/transitions-between-panoramas-in-three-js?rq=1

Comment: Google Maps actually has a 3d representation of the world. It's not just panoramas. It uses that 3d data to map the various parts of the panorama to a simplified (low poly) model, slides the camera using that 3D model, the cross fades to the new panorama. you're not going to be able to repo that effective without 3D data

Comment: One way is to use simple 3d world like gman said . In this case you can walk in any arrow . In other way if you wanna panorama method you will need prepared 3d video in some way . Panorama use textures , you will need to record all camera movement where you want to navigate with your app . Use two switching geometry (cube in your case) One is always current and seconds is future (video textures) . Use opacity fadein fadeout effect . On arrow keypress just load next sequence of current panorama video texture. Make arrow enabled only on start or end of movement line.

Comment: maximum zoom-in level is based on camera parameters .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Detecting WHEN to transition:**

In the example given, the mouse events are all given. The zoom is handled in `onDocumentMouseWheel` by adjusting the camera's `fov` property. "Zoom In" reduces the `fov`, and "Zoom Out" increases it. It would be trivial to detect when the `fov` has reached a minimum/maximum value, which would trigger your transition to a new scene.

**Detecting WHERE to transition:**

The next step is determining into which new scene you will transition. You could do something hotspot-like, where you shoot a ray from the camera to see if it hit a particular place (for example a `THREE.Sphere` which you have strategically positioned). But for simplicity, let's assume you only have the 6 directions you mentioned, and that you're still using the example's mouse control.

Camera movement is handled in `onDocumentMouseMove` by updating the `lat` and `lon` variables (which appear to be in degrees). (*Note: It seems `lon` increases without bounds, so for clarity it might be good to give it a reset value so it can only ever be between 0.0-359.99 or something.*) You can get all math-y to check the corners better, or you could simply check your 45's:

```
if(lat > 45){
    // you're looking up
}
else if(lat < -45){
    // you're looking down
}
else{
    // you're looking at a side, check "lon" instead
}
```

Your look direction determines to which scene you will transition, should you encounter your maximum zoom.

**Transitioning**

There are lots of ways you can do this. You could simply replace the texture on the cube that makes up the panorama. You could swap in a totally different `THREE.Scene`. You could reset the camera--or not. You could play with the lights dimming out/in while the transition happens. You could apply some post-processing to obscure the transition effect. This part is all style, and it's all up to you.

**Addressing @Marquizzo's concern:**

The lighting is simply a suggestion for a transition. The example doesn't use a light source because the material is a `MeshBasicMaterial` (doesn't require lighting). The example also doesn't use `scene.background`, but applies the texture to an inverted sphere. There are other methods one can use if you simply can't affect the "brightness" of the texture (such as CSS transitions).

I added the following code the the example to make it fade in and out, just as an example.

```
// These are in the global scope, defined just before the call to init();
// I moved "mesh" to the global scope to access its material during the animation loop.
var mesh = null,
    colorChange = -0.01;

// This code is inside the "update" function, just before the call to renderer.render(...);
// It causes the color of the material to vary between white/black, giving the fading effect.
mesh.material.color.addScalar(colorChange);
if(mesh.material.color.r + colorChange < 0 || mesh.material.color.r + colorChange > 1){ // not going full epsilon checking for an example...
    colorChange = -colorChange;
}
```

One could even affect the opacity value of the material to make one sphere fade away, and another sphere fade into place.

My main point is that the transition can be accomplished in a variety of ways, and that it's up to @Vad to decide what kind of effect to use.

Comment: Lights dimming don't have an effect on the scene.background attribute after you assign it to a CubeTexture. I think he's asking if there's a way to do a fade transition between one CubeTexture to another.